# from Cython.Distutils import build_ext as _build_ext . ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'

Tags: python, cython

I tried to install the below packages in requirements.txt, with Python 3.7.8

`pyarrow==0.9.0 pandas==0.25.0 fastparquet==0.2.1`

However, when pip comes to installing pyarrow, it fails with the following:

```
\`$ pip install -r requirements.txt
Collecting pyarrow==0.9.0
Downloading pyarrow-0.9.0.tar.gz (8.5 MB)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 8.5/8.5 MB 46.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─\> \[6 lines of output\]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "\<string\>", line 36, in \<module\>
File "\<pip-setuptools-caller\>", line 34, in \<module\>
File "/tmp/pip-install-yl6pqzo3/pyarrow_d053191e67b3424b8233a2ca5fe77fad/setup.py", line 29, in \<module\>
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext as \_build_ext
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'
\[end of output\]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed
× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─\> See above for output.
note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1\`
```

I confirmed python and pip refer to the venv python.
I also tried installing/upgrading/uninstalling&instsalling cython via pip but they didn't work.
I also tried

```
pip install pyarrow==0.9.0.post1
```

and it failed either.

Could you please help me solve this? Thank you!

Comment: trying `cython==0.29.11` or some older version of cython.

Comment: @Ahmed AEK Thanks for your advice! I had tried cython == 0.29.13, and just tried cython==0.29.11, cython == 0.29.10, and cython == 0.28.6 per your suggestion. However, the same error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython' happened.